# First time javascript help needed

Tags: javascript

Can some one please let me know what is wrong with the following javascript. Its suppose to display the time and date but nothing but the HTML title is displayed. I am getting this from a javascript book im using to learn with and i think it may be to old now and things may have changed, or ive made a mistake.

```html
<html>

<head><title>Date time</title></head>

<body>
<h1> Time and Date </h1>

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type="textjavascript">
 now = new Date();
 localtime = now.toString();
 utctime = now.toGMTString();
 document.write ("<b> local time: </b>" + localtime + "<BR>");
 document.write ("<b> UTC time: </b>" + utctime +);
 
 document.write("Hello World!");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Try this: `now = new Date();
localtime = now.toString();
utctime = now.toGMTString();
document.write("<b> local time: </b>" + localtime + "<BR>");
document.write("<b> UTC time: </b>" + utctime );`

Comment: `document.write ("<b> UTC time: </b>" + utctime +);` , there's a unnecessary `+` dangling here

Comment: this did not work either. I cant see much difference from what you wrote to what i already have. I am saving the document as a .html and uploading to my server, i assume this is correct.

Answer (score 3):

**Issue #1**. It doesn't work because script block is not recognized as JS because of invalid type attribute:

```
type="textjavascript"
```

Should be `type="text/javascript"`

**Issue #2**. Once you fix this, make sure to fix this line too:

```
 + utctime +);
       //  ^ ---- remove this "+"
```

**Issue #3**. Throw away the book you read. It's totally outdated. Reason:

- don't use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) - it's used in very specific cases, your is not the one of those.
- don't specify `LANGUAGE="JavaScript"` and `type="text/javascript"` they are redundant.

Finally, learn DOM methods like [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), [appendChild](http://appendChild), [createTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode), [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), etc., there are many of them.

You could rewrite your example in multiple ways, for example:

```html
<html>
    
    <head><title>Date time</title></head>
    
    <body>
        <h1> Time and Date </h1>
        <div class="date"></div>
    
    <script>
     var now = new Date();
     var localtime = now.toString();
     var utctime = now.toGMTString();
     
     var container = document.querySelector('.date');
     
     container.innerHTML = 
         "<b> local time: </b>" + localtime + "<BR>" +
         "<b> UTC time: </b>" + utctime;
         
        document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello World!"));
    </script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 errors in your code:

- The MIME type should be set to `text/javascript` instead of `textjavascript`
- There is a syntax error in `"<b> UTC time: </b>" + utctime +` <-- Remove the trailing `+`

Comment: thanks Chris it was the / missing in textjavascript. i thought i went over this with a fine tooth comb but still missed this.

Answer (score 0):

First change, <script type="text/javascript">, then

Just remove the '+' after utctime in document.write, it will work, that variable has no string to append ,so no '+' is needed.

```
now = new Date();
localtime = now.toString();
utctime = now.toGMTString();
document.write ("<b> local time: </b>" + localtime + "<BR>");
document.write ("<b> UTC time: </b>" + utctime );

document.write("Hello World!");
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have issue in below line.

```
document.write ("<b> UTC time: </b>" + utctime +);
```

YOu have added extra "+" at last .

SO proper working code should be as below.

https://jsfiddle.net/tdc6dkn6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the + sign at the end of the following statement :

```
document.write ("<b> UTC time: </b>" + utctime +);
```

It should be :

```
document.write ("<b> UTC time: </b>" + utctime);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head><title>Date time</title></head>

<body>
<h1> Time and Date </h1>

<script>
    var now = new Date();
    var localtime = now.toString();
    var utctime = now.toGMTString();
    document.write ("<b> local time: </b>" + localtime + "<BR>");
    document.write ("<b> UTC time: </b>" + utctime);

    document.write("Hello World!");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a redundant `+` in the code. Also there is an error in the `type` as well. Check this out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    now = new Date();
    localtime = now.toString();
    utctime = now.toGMTString();
    document.write ("<b> local time: </b>" + localtime + "<br>");
    document.write ("<b> UTC time: </b>" + utctime);

    document.write("Hello World!");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change  `type="textjavascript"` to `type="text/javascript"` and take out the extra `+` in `document.write ("<b> UTC time: </b>" + utctime +);`.